# Alternative to MySQL UNION

Tags: mysql

What would be an alternative to this

```
SELECT  i.title AS title,i.category AS category FROM table_a  WHERE REGEXP 'news'
UNION 
SELECT i.name AS title,i.categoryname AS category FROM table_b WHERE REGEXP 'news'
```

without using UNION? The issue we have is that we must select more rows from table_a and UNION must have rows # match. We can fake the rows in table_b by selecting different row but it just gets to confusing when we have 7 or 8 tables to mix and none of them have same number of rows or matching names. We cant use JOIN since we have noting to join them on.

Thank you!

Comment: You can use join, you just hard code the criteria e.g. On SomeField = 'Fred', to avoid getting a cartesian product. Course with 7 or 8 tables that's going to be as much of a tip as what you have.

Comment: way to much since I also have php conditions as to what table NOT to include

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fill in the blanks with null, or some other constant that makes sense thusly:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d FROM t1
UNION
SELECT a, b, null, 0 FROM t2
UNION
SELECT '', b, c, 1 FROM t3
```

Comment: What he WANTS might not be what he NEEDS :-)

Comment: I agree that he probably needs a union to do this so say in your answer why using UNION is actually the best way to do this.

Comment: Nailed it mate!  null  saved me . should have asked this yesterday , killed myself with faking rows in 8 tables. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
...UNION SELECT i.name AS title,'empty' AS category FROM table_b WHERE REGEXP 'news'
```

What you select doesn't have to be necessary an column. If you have to UNION 7 or 8 tables in one result it may be that your underlying data model could be improved, but maybe you just can't change this?

Comment: I dont think that the model could be improved more than it is now since none of the tables match any other and this is ajax search with php conditions to exclude specific ones. so UNION is the simplest way to go.